# Avoiding framed forwarding for web app on port 8080 with DNS

Tags: http, dns, playframework-2.0

I have a play application running on port 8080. I currently forward to this by using

```
http://ip_address:8080
```

as my 'URL to forward to' in my forwarding service control panel.

The problem with this is: frame forwarding is used and I think this may be stopping Google Analytic for working.

I have control over DNS

A, CNAME, AAAA, TXT and NS records

&

DNS Service records

For other websites in the past running on port 80 I have simply created an A record with the destination as the server IP address, however because I am using port 8080 in this case, this does not work.

What is the best way to go about getting away from framed forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put port numbers into the DNS resource record (there's a notable exception, namely SRV records, but as client support for those is rather spotty, those won't be much help). A nameserver commonly resolves hostnames to ip addresses - no directory/file names, no port numbers.

You can use a permanent redirect, which is a webserver facility, used to tell web clients to contact a different webhost. In order to use that, you need a webserver which responds to requests on port 80, and knows that requests concerning your zone must be redirected to your actual webserver. Very similar to the iframe solution you've been already using, but a permanent redirect instead of iframe.

If your reason for dropping the current iframe approach isn't that you, for example, want to get rid of decorative framing, ads, "branding" etc  (with those, a permanent redirect would help), but want to cease using an intermediate webserver, adding another level of indirection to the queries, there's little you can do:
your firewall may be able to do port redirection, meaning that the incoming requests will hit your gateway/firewall on port 80, where the request is sent on to port 8080 where the webserver is actually listening. Another possibility could be, but requiring again another webserver, listening to port 80, to set up proxying: incoming requests to that webserver will be served from a cache on that server, which is populated and occasionally refreshed as result of that webserver querying your webserver on port 8080.

Even though with the latter suggestion an additional webserver will be existing, there'd be no visible indirection, as it would be transparent to clients: The web files are produced by the first server which is hit, even if they are once every so often taken from another server.